# How do I get pass this docker error Error: Could not find or load main class com.xxx.yyy.discoveryserver.DiscoveryServerApplication

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and docker-compose. I am getting this error with docker after running docker compose up -d command "Error: Could not find or load main class com.xxx.yyy.discoveryserver.DiscoveryServerApplication".
But when I run the same app from the iDE, it runs fine

This is my docker-compose code for the said module

```
discovery-server:
   image: xxx/discoveryserver:latest
   container_name: xxx_discoveryserver
   pull_policy: always
   ports:
     - "8761:8761"
   expose:
     - "8761"
   command:
     - -p 8761
   environment:
     - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
   healthcheck:
     test: "exit 0"
   depends_on:
     zipkin:
       condition: service_healthy
```

and this is the application.properties file

```
server.port=8761
#spring.zipkin.base-url=http://zipkin:9411
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://myusername:mypassword@discovery-server:8761/eureka

eureka.instance.hostname=discovery-server
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

eureka.username=${EUREKA_USERNAME:myusername}
eureka.password=${EUREKA_PASSWORD:mypassword}
spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false
```

and here is my docker file

```
FROM openjdk:22-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 as builder
WORKDIR extracted
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar app.jar extract

FROM openjdk:22-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/ ./
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Without seeing for example the `discoveryserver` Dockerfile it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: David, thank you for your response. I just added more details to the question. Thank you

Comment: (For reference, this is similar to [Spring Boot's recommended Dockerfile setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/container-images.html#container-images.dockerfiles), though the documented setup will use a Linux base image rather than a Windows one.)